# Sort array of Custom Objects by date range Swift

Tags: ios, sorting, range, nsdate

I am having an array of Custom Objects and each object having a date property of NSDate.I want to sort now the Array by using a start and end date.I want to get all the objects whose date matches with start date and end date and in between dates.

i really do not know about doing this.Any suggestions and sample code are much helpful and appreciated.

Comment: We *really do not know about* the language.

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way you can do this is:

```
- (NSArray *)selectObjectsWithBeginDate:(NSDate *)dateBegin endDate:(NSDate *)dateEnd {
    NSMutableArray *selections = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (CustomObject *obj in objectArray) {

        if ([obj.date compare:dateBegin] == NSOrderedDescending && [obj.date compare:dateEnd] == NSOrderedAscending) {
            [selections addObject:obj];
        }
    }
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:selections];
}
```

You just need to be able ti compare two NSDate objects.

Comment: if i want to exclude objects that matches the start and end dates from the resulting array what should i do?